# Workflow Comment popup does not show up in workbox

Tags: workflow

I am using **Sitecore 9.1**.

I made a `custom workflow` and assigned a few actions and commands to it as the below picture shows:

[image]

The `Default Comment Template` field is set to the standard comment template, and `Suppress comment` is *not* `checked`.

My problem is that, whenever I `accept or reject` an item within this workflow, the comment popup never appears. I am using the buttons highlighted below 
[image]

I've been searching online for a while but have only found articles about wanting to hide the comment popup, but nothing about it not appearing in the first place..

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Please make sure popups are blocked on your browser.

Comment: @AmitabhVyas they are not blocked,i made sure

Comment: The question should point out, Workbox is being used here - this is not Sitecore's standard workflow in play.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I did mention that I made a custom workflow at the beginning :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with it :-)   You're using Workbox for your approval flow, which changes things up a bit.

Comment: ah okay, I edited the question title then :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For bulk workflow operations there is a setting which decides whether the comment box should be displayed or not.

Add

```
<setting name="Workbox.SingleCommentForBulkOperation">
    <patch:delete />
</setting>
<setting name="Workbox.SingleCommentForBulkOperation" value="true" />
```

setting via a patch file to you `App_Config`.

The first line makes sure that if there is a setting with `false` already there, it will be removed.